# Hello world of RESTful based on Jersey and Jetty

Tags: rest, intellij-idea, jersey, jetty

I'm following [this guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html) to build my hello world web service and get kind of stuck, here are my codes:

`MyResource.java:`

```
package com.example;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

`pom.xml:`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ts</groupId>
<artifactId>mtest</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>mtest Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>mtest</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`web.xml:`

```
<web-app version="3.0"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<!-- Servlet declaration can be omitted in which case
     it would be automatically added by Jersey -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myresource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now my problems are:

1. After launching Jetty, I can get a hello world of my jsp from `http://localhost:8080/`, but `http://localhost:8080/myresource` returns 404
2. Intellij complains `Element web-app must be declared`

Comment: `<url-pattern>` and `@Path` is redundant. With what you have you need to access `/myresource/myresource`. Change the `<url-pattern>` to `/api/*` and use `/api/myresource`

Comment: Also, unless you are building an embedded jetty app, those dependencies are unnecessary. I would just use `jersey-container-servlet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your servlet declaration in the web.xml like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

that should work. And sometimes the path needs a bar like this.

```
@Path("/myresource")
```

And see that, if you put

```
<url-pattern>/myresource/*</url-pattern>
```

you have to hit

http://localhost:8080/myresource/myresource

one by your web configuration, and another by the path of your resource.

but, if you are trying this in tomcat, you need to include the artifactId too, like this:

> http://localhost:8080/mtest/myresource/myresource

I hope that this help you.

Comment: My servlet declaration is fine, the only problem is the path, thanks for the help anyway.